# unable to select a name from autocomplete list

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing the autocomplete list for the textboxes.

When user type some character in the `textbox` it shows the autocomplete list from where the user can select the name, but if user doesn't want to select any name from the autocomplete list and click outside the list, the autocomplete list
disappears and the code for this is as below:

```css
#country1:not(:focus)+.list-group {
  display: none;
}
```

But my working functionality had broke and it is not allowing to select the name from the autocomplete list in any of the textboxes.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/y4UNoYtuJFYhjpN0mtWS?p=preview

#### CSS:

```css
#country1:not(:focus)+.list-group {
  display: none;
}

#country2:not(:focus)+.list-group {
  display: none;
}

#country3:not(:focus)+.list-group {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly :

- And add in the complete method(), the value of the field to the list
- Use ng-mousedown instead ng-click (for the click to execute before losing focus)

  ```
   $scope.complete = function (string, labelSel) {
          var output = [];

          if(string !== "")
            output.push(string); // push your string at first 

          angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function (country) {
              if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                  output.push(country);
              }
          });
          //... etc
    }
  ```

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/rlYx5oXTqbfBloid5Jue?p=preview

Comment: It is breaking my existing functionality..When user type a character in the textbox it shows the autocomplete list and when user click outside the list or esc button i want to hide the displayed autocomplete list, but with your code, it is not allowing to hide the list when user click out side of the autocomplete list if he doesn't want to select a name from the list..Any inputs?

Comment: Okay. Indeed the focus is removed before the click is executed. Same for ng-blur and ng-focus

Comment: oh ok. Can you please edit your code and provide some inputs for this..@Stys

Comment: Ok i find use ng-mousedown instead ng-click, http://next.plnkr.co/edit/rlYx5oXTqbfBloid5Jue?p=preview&preview

Comment: It's done on the post, and for the "esc button", i think you must use a keydown event